# Android AlarmManager triggered immediately even with correct parameters?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am setting an AlamManager from the onCreate of my main Activity.

Here is the method

```
public void scheduleAdsUpdateAlarm() {
    long THEE_HOURS = 3 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    long THREE_MINUTES= 3*60*1000;
    long UNTIL_FIRST_TRIGGER = THREE_MINUTES;

    // Construct an intent that will execute the AlarmReceiver
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AdsUpdateAlarmReceiver.class);

    // Create a PendingIntent to be triggered when the alarm goes off
    final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, AdsUpdateAlarmReceiver.REQUEST_CODE,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    if(alarm != null){
        alarm.cancel(pIntent);
        alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, UNTIL_FIRST_TRIGGER,
                THREE_MINUTES, pIntent);
    }
}
```

As you can see the alarm is set to run every three hours with the initial start after three minutes.

**Problem** is that the alarm goes off immediately when the onCreate and the following alarm setup is called. I don't understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, UNTIL_FIRST_TRIGGER,
THREE_MINUTES, pIntent);
```

should be changed to:

```
alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + UNTIL_FIRST_TRIGGER, THREE_MINUTES, pIntent);
```

since the second parameter in alarm.setInexactRepeating isn't a milliseconds from now value but an actual time value.